# Notification - Change notification icon color according to activity theme

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to develop an App that will notify people about some actions...

---

The problem is that i want to create a smallIcon drawable that will change its color dynamically owing to status Bar color or activity theme

[image]

---

I've a white drawable icon with transparent background and tried this way but icon color is always white.

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notification")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.white_logo)
            .setContent(contentView)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change colors on icons as android 5.x and above, but you can change the color of the icon when you slide down

```
private void showNotification(Context context) {
    Log.d(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Displaying Notification");
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    mBuilder.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("EarthQuakeAlert");
    mBuilder.setContentText("It's been a while you have checked out earthquake data!");
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

and your output will be this:

[image]

[image]

Also, if you change your targetSdkVersion in gradle or manifest file below 21, the notification icon will be colorful. (From sdk level 21 there is a white filter on the notification icon.) (not recommended!)

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

and you can see this. But is not recommended because in higher apis you will see a blank box and the notification will not appear.

[image]

Comment: when i launch the activity with the status bar color of white icons should be gray and vice - versa . It is just setting color tint permanently...